# Should we not @synthesize any more?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Now with the release of the new Xcode it has been said that properties get synthesized automatically, and indeed they are accessible without synthesizing as long as you use the `'_'` prefix. But I recently found out that Xcode allows me to access those properties in another way - using a `'self.*'` prefix (where the * is the name of the property).

Is this correct? Should I use it? Could it harm my code?

Thanks you.

Comment: This is correct. It is a feature of the new compiler.

Comment: why is this new? Properties are always accessed using the dot syntax...

Comment: The `self.property` has been available for a while...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `_yourProperty` you access the instance variable, with `self.yourProperty` its getter/setter. As long you are sure you have no costumized getter/setter, both is the same (with a very small performance penalty for getter/setter). However, in general, you should use the getter/setter approach (except in getter/setter themself) in case you will change your code later.

**EDIT:**

@Vanthel: The underline is pure convention. Without `@synthesize` (or with `@synthesize foo`), the compiler generates for a property `foo` a variable `_foo`. However, by `@synthesize foo = my_bar` you assign the variable `my_bar` to be accessed by the accessors of `foo`.

Comment: Could you clarify the use of the underscore prefix in a separate paragraph?